# Python geoprocessing performance

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing

I'm using ArcGIS Server 10.0. I have a python geoprocessing that takes a lot of time. The geoprocessing calculates geometries using points, polygons, buffers, and cursors.

I'm also using sql queries with the SdeExecuteSQL function. This function seems to take time too. Is it possible to optimize this?

Do you have any hint of how to optimize the geoprocessing?

Would it be shorter in time if I used the Java API?

Comment: What software? What does your code look like?

Comment: My code contains more than 3000 lines.
To resume, it reads data from database, creates and modifies geometries and non spatial objects, using some business rules. Then inserts the changes into database.
I'd like to know if in general the arcpy is slower than Java ArcObjects.

Comment: Well without seeing your code it's going to be hard to tell what issues you might be having.  I would suggest you put some timers in the code and see if you can find the bottleneaks.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using ArcPy 10.0 cursors in your code and this will be appreciably slower than ArcObjects.

If you use the **[ArcPy 10.1/10.2 Data Access cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)** you will find them much (perhaps 10x) faster than ArcPy 10.0 cursors.

Comment: OK thanks!
I'm also using sql queries with the SdeExecuteSQL function. This function takes time too. Is it possible to optimize this?

Comment: Could you edit your Question to include this additional information, please?  However, it would appear that this may represent an additional question so perhaps consider posting a new one for it.

Comment: @PolyGeo, yo_haha is using v10.0 so data access cursors are not an option.